# Función Área de un rectangulo PHP

Tags: php, function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    function rectangulo($base, $altura){
        $area = $base*$altura; 
        return $area;
        echo "Un rectangle de base $base i alçada $altura té un àrea de $area";
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

No me sale he de hacer dos versiones, una con la
visualizacion dentro de la función y otra con la visualizacion fuera de la función.Un echo dentro y fuera básicamente. Aprender argumentos y retorno de valor

Comment: Necesitas poner el echo antes del return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error en tu función, si retornar antes de hacer un **echo** no podrás visualizar lo que mandas a imprimir, puedes hacerlo de dos maneras:

```
<?php
  function rectangulo($base, $altura){
    $area = $base*$altura; 
    return $area;
  }

  $base = 2;
  $altura = 4;
  $area= rectangulo($base,$altura);
  echo "Un rectangle de base $base i alçada $altura té un àrea de $area";

?>
```

ó

```
<?php
  function rectangulo($base, $altura){
    $area = $base*$altura; 
    echo "Un rectangle de base $base i alçada $altura té un àrea de $area";
    return $area;
  }

  $area= rectangulo(2,4);

?>
```

Comment: Exacto esto era lo que buscaba gracias David ahora los pruebo pero de pinta es eso !

Comment: Que bueno que te puede ayudar, si te sirvio me podrias dar el visto bueno a mi respuesta? gracias @InfoTipsconJavitoBCN

Comment: Me dice que espere 40 segundos . Si ahora lo hago está todo perfecto!

Answer (score 0):

Para que la función te trabaje y te retorne un valor; debería estar de este modo:

```
<?php

function rectangulo($base, $altura){
        $area = $base*$altura; 
        echo "Un rectangle de base $base i alçada $altura té un àrea de $area";
        return $area;
    }

rectangulo(12, 3);
```

**LO QUE HICE**

1.- Después de la operación matemática que obtiene el área declaro el echo que imprime el valor

2.- Al final declaro el return para que la estructura de la función al ser invocada sepa que tiene que devolver un resultado

3.- Finalmente necesito invocar a la función para ver su resultado en pantalla, haciendo `nombreFuncion(parametro1, parámetro2);`

4.- Si colocas el `return` antes del echo, entonces la función procesa hasta la multiplicación pero no imprimirá el mensaje que haz declarado y entonces deberías hacer un echo por fuera al invocar la función

Comment: Me funciona poniendo la linea de rectangulo(12,3); al principio de todo ya que sino se queda pantalla blanca gracias salu2!